# Optional 1:1 relationship in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to create what I think would be either called an optional 1:1 or possibly 0..1:0..1 relationship in Entity Framework.  I want to be able to have navigation properties on both objects.

I am using Entity Framework's Fluent API over an existing database schema.

For simplicity, lets assume the following tables:

```
Car
    Id int not null

Driver
    Id int not null
    CarId int null unique
```

Using the following classes:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Car { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is a Car and a Driver can exist independent of one another, but when a Driver gets associated with a Car it is a mutually exclusive association: the Driver can only be associated with that Car and that Car can only be associated to that Driver.

I tried the following fluent configuration:

Inside Driver's Configuration:

```
HasOptional(d => d.Car)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .Map(d => d.MapKey("CarId"));
```

And inside the Car configuration

```
HasOptional(c => cDriver)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal()
    .Map(d => d.MapKey("CarId"));
```

When I try this I get the following:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
>   (203,6) : error 0019: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'CarId' was already defined.

Is there a way to model this scenario with navigation properties on both objects in Entity Framework?

Comment: Why do you have `d.MapKey("CarId")` on both? Wouldn't one be `CarId` and the other `DriverId`?

Comment: The Car tables does not have a DriverId column.  If there were a DriverId column in the Car table it would allow for a car pointing to a driver that differs from the one pointing to it - it is either 1:1 or 0:0

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without Fluent API:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? DriverId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DriverId")]
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to check if the Driver already has a car, to guarantee that he can have only one.

Comment: This is where I started and when I didn't have Car.Driver it worked fine, once I added Car.Driver with the annotation as above it results in the error ```Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Driver' and 'Car'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.```

Comment: All cars must have a driver? All drivers must have a car?

Comment: No, the relationship is optional but exclusive - I think EF is having difficulty thinking its supposed to be 1:1 or something instead of being either 0:0 or 1:1

Comment: If it is exclusive, the primarykey of the car must be the primarykey of the driver... But in that case, a car cannot exist without a driver... Is that right?

Comment: But any car can be associated to any driver assuming neither party is already in an association, and a Car can exist without a Driver and vice versa, so there isn't a way for their primary keys to match since they are both created independently then later may be associated.

Comment: There's a not ellegant way, but I it works. You can make a 1:n relationship  and check if the driver already has a car... see my edited answer... Your problem is complicated, to solve this we need to find someone with more experience.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set it up in both fluent classes. I'm surprised that is the error that you received, and not that the relationship is already set up.

Your Drive class will need the CarId as part of the class:

```
public class Driver 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Make this int? if a Driver can exist without a Car
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Car { get; set; }
}
```

Then you just need this in the Fluent Config file for Driver, and nothing in the one for Car.

```
HasOptional(d => d.Car)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .Map(d => d.MapKey("CarId"));
```

Comment: I tried that and it complained that the property JobId was being double defined ```Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(204,6) : error 0019: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'CarId' was already defined.```.  If I remove the CarId property I then get the issue ```Invalid column name 'Driver_ID'``` which is what caused me to think I needed fluent config on both ends

Comment: With what I have above, is your Car C# object the same as you have above? You have no dependency setup in Car's fluent setup?